# useContext returns undefined when my redux store updates

Tags: reactjs, redux, use-context

I am having trouble understanding why my useContext value updates from the expected values to undefined when the redux store is updated. I am using create context to house my socket connection for my discussions. The following is my context class

```
import React, { createContext, useRef } from 'react'


export const WebSocketContext = createContext()

export default ({ children }) => {
    const webSocket = useRef(null);
    let ws;
    const openedDiscussionID = useSelector(state => state.presence.discussionId || '')
    
    const sendMessages = (messageObject) => {
        webSocket.current.send(JSON.stringify(messageObject))
    }

    if (!webSocket.current){
        webSocket.current = new WebSocket(``) 
        webSocket.current.onmessage = (message) => {
            const discussionMessage = JSON.parse(message.data)
        };

        ws = {
            webSocket: webSocket.current,
            sendMessages
        }

    }

    return(
        <WebSocketContext.Provider value={ws}>
            {children}
        </WebSocketContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

I am currently using it in my parent component called projectDetailContainer,

```
import WebSocketProvider from '../../redux-state/middleware/socketService'


function ProjectDetailContainer() {
return (
        <WebSocketProvider>
        <div>parent component</div>
        </WebSocketProvider>
    )
}

export default ProjectDetailContainer
```

somewhere down the chain, I have the following discussion component:

```
import { WebSocketContext } from '../../redux-state/middleware/socketService'
function DiscussionOptionContainer() {
    const ws = useContext(WebSocketContext)
...
    useEffect(() => {
        if(openedDiscussion.title?.length){
            dispatch(setOpenDiscussion(openedDiscussion))
        }
    },[openedDiscussion])

    const sendMessage = () => {
        const mes = {
            action:'discussion',
            message:{
                customerId:'7240304',
                projectId:projectId,
                message:message,
                itemId:openedDiscussion.discussionId,
                sender: me
            }
        }
        debugger
        ws.sendMessages(mes)
    }

...}
```

The thing I noticed was that as soon as the app loads, I see the sendMessages function being returned but as soon as the dispatch occurs, it changes the ws (useContext) to undefined. If I comment out the part that updates the redux store, it works as expected. My theory is that the redux store provider is higher in the chain than my WebSocketProvider but i cant confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useSelector` triggers a rerender when selected value changes. `ws` is undefined by default and gets a value if `webSocket.current` is falsy. And it seems to happen only on the initial render. Every consecutive render will set `ws` to undefined and pass it to `WebSocketContext.Provider`.

Try moving `ws = {.....}` outside condition.